# sharepoint designer workflow to extract string

Tags: designer-workflow

I have a file name like "filename-abc_111"
I need to store abc in a variable and 111 in 2nd variable.
I have seen action provided by designer for extract string but that seems to be for specific character. our file name character could vary everytime so could not use it. any option to get this. Thanks

Comment: For added clarity, will it always be 2 sets of 3 chars?

Answer (score 0):

Unless you standardize your filename Scheme for your end-users or the system that is uploading the files this is nearly an impossible task to know where to split the string, unless there is a pre-determined length perhaps. Best thing you could do for yourself going forward is to ask all end-users to adhere to a schema (and correct the ones already upoaded) like TrueFile-CompanyName_SpecialID i.e. myFile-myABCCompany_12345. Or you could create two columns within the document library and ask the end users to please fill in the properties and go back and add them for already uploaded files (If you know all the companies then I would create a drop down field type as to standardize the company names you don't want repeat company names like myABCCompany and MY ABC Company, defeats the purpose), with the second recommendation you could create a workflow and update the file name field by concatenating and appedning the company name field and special ID field with the original file name the entered to get a schema like myFile-myABCCompany_12345

As for how to actually split the values and such once you have the schema fix with the end users check out this article:

http://documentmanagementworkflowinfo.com/sharepoint-2013/sharepoint-designer-workflow-string-actions.htm